# How to continuously run this

Tags: websocket, centos

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-live-score-widget-using-php-web-sockets/) on setting up a websocket to live update my website, which I've followed and it works fine, however, I need to keep a putty terminal open connected to my CentOS server for the command `php bin/server.php`. How can I leave that command running constantly? Could I set it up as a service, or would I different approach be better?

EDIT: I've found using (from bin folder) `php server.php &` will run the script in the background, so I can do other things via ssh, but if I close the connection it stops running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this `nohup php server.php > /dev/null &` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231539/run-a-php-script-as-a-background-process-in-wamp-server) which seems to do the trick :)

I also got a bit stuck stopping the script... I used `ps` to get php's process ID and then killed using `kill [id]`